# Comparison operator == is not working, how do I make it work? [cpp]

Tags: c++, if-statement, equals

I am getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\*******\Documents\CodeBlocksProjects\encryptText\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\Users\*******\Documents\CodeBlocksProjects\encryptText\main.cpp|14|error: no match for 'operator==' in 'givenText == 1'|
C:\Users\*******\Documents\CodeBlocksProjects\encryptText\main.cpp|25|error: no match for 'operator==' in 'givenText == 2'|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "encrypt.h"
#include "decrypt.h"


using namespace std;

int main() {
startOver:
    string givenText, pass;
    cout << "Encrypt (1) or Decrypt (2)?" << endl << "Choice: ";
    getline(cin, givenText);
    if (givenText == 1) {
        cout << endl << "Plain-Text: ";
        getline(cin, givenText);
        cout << endl << "Password: ";
        getline(cin, pass);
        cout << endl << encrypt(givenText, pass) << endl << "Restart? (Y/N)";
        getline(cin, givenText);
        if (givenText == "Y") {
            cout << endl;
            goto startOver;
        }
    } else if (givenText == 2) {
        cout << endl << "Ciphered-Text: ";
        getline(cin, givenText);
        cout << endl << "Password: ";
        getline(cin, pass);
        cout << endl << decrypt(givenText, pass) << endl << "Restart? (Y/N)";
        getline(cin, givenText);
        if (givenText == "Y") {
            cout << endl;
            goto startOver;
        }
    } else {
        cout << endl << "Please input 1 or 2 for choice." << endl;
        goto startOver;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I thought it would be as simple as a if (x == y) sort of thing, but I guess not. What am I suppose to do to fix this? Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no implicit type conversion for your string, so you either needed to:

a) change your test to compare strings:  if (givenText == "1")

or

b) parse your givenText to an integer before comparing:  if (atoi(givenText.c_str()) == 1)

Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

can't compare string to int directly. use quotes around the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The datatype on `givenText` is string. You are comparing it to an integer.

There are two ways to solve this, the simple one:

```
if (givenText == "1")
```

Which will take consider 1 as a string.

The other opion (which will work with 1, 01, 0randomCharacters01 etc etc), is `int givenTextInt = atoi(givenText.c_str());`

And now you can compare like this:

```
 if (givenTextInt == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2 are integers, you can't compare them with a string.  Compare "1" and "2" instead.